# Changing the style when clicked the input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change the style of the input and some other buttons when clicked the input.

Here is my `HTML` content:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .body {
    z-index: 2;
    .logo {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 39px;
    }
    .search {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      input {
        width: 702px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 42px;
        border: 1px #CBCBCB;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px #00000029;
        background-image: url('../../assets/search-icon.svg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 18px 15px;
        padding-left: 52px;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
      }
    }
    .buttons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      .search-button {
        background-color: #FF4A4A;
        border-radius: 9px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000042;
        padding: 11px 22px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        width: 181px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        margin-right: 13px;
      }
      .tour-button {
        background-color: #F7931E;
        border-radius: 9px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000042;
        padding: 11px 22px;
        border: none;
        width: 181px;
        outline: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="assets/logo.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search anything around the world ..." (click)="clickMessage($event)">
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="link">
            <p>powered by <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
        </div> -->
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="search-button">Search</button>
      <button class="tour-button">Take me on tour</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to remove the buttons and logo and move the input location when someone clicks the input with angular?

I tried with `input:focus` but it wont work the way I want because I want to remove the buttons and logo.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example? Also, tell us what exactly you want to do (like what style).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `focus` event and do what you want in your event function.

Do like this:

```
<input type="search" (focus)="focusFunction()" />
```

And you can bind your button with `*ngIf="show"` directive in `focusFunction` function change the value of show to `true`.

```
<button class="search-button" *ngIf="show">Search</button>
<button class="tour-button"   *ngIf="show">Take me on tour</button>
```

Same as thing for style of input : `[style.top]="top"`

```
<input
    type="search"
    (focus)="focusFunction()"
    placeholder="Search anything around the world ..."
    [style.top]="top"
  />

focusFunction() {
    console.log("input focused");
    this.show = false;
    this.top = '200px';
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-qlymuu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is working sample I wrote for you.